# SP Online: Lists and Quick Editing is broken

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

This happens in Edge and Chrome on different computers. Does not appear to be cookie or browser related.

Apologies for the poor description, I'm new to SPO and SharePoint in general but we're having an interesting issue that doesn't look to be isolated.

When a user is working on a list and changes from one list to another, the properties sheet (Quick View?) does not reflect the categories related to that list. See the screenshots below:

User is initially working in the Incident Response list. Quick View shows all the proper items/drop-downs/etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba5bF.png

2. User then switches to another list (IT Request List in my example)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hd6K.png

See the properties sheet. The items are still related to the Incident Response list. What's happening here? This appears to happen across the board with any list and looks to keep the properties of the initial list that was accessed.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

2nd edit: I think what I'm trying to describe is the "Quick Edit" mode. That appears to be broken when switching between lists.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your second list IS using a custom list form.

You can go to the second list settings > Form and select "Use the default SP form". Then check the results.

[image]

Comment: I was hoping it would be this easy. I checked all of the various lists and they're all using that option, "Use the default SharePoint form."

Comment: Test changing another browser. Of course, you can clear the cache of your browser.

Comment: Yep. Doesn't matter the browser or the computer. Have seen it happen across at least 3-4 different machines and in different browsers. Some people were using edge as their primary and others (including myself) use Chrome. Same behavior.

Comment: I would suggest you submit a service request in the Microsoft365 admin center > Support > New service request. Then there will be more professional engineers(SPO) to help you solve your problem.